# Count all child objects across class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If a model `Parent` has two child models: `AChild` and `BChild` such that:

```
@parent.a_childs.count = 1
@parent.b_childs.count = 2
```

Is there an existing method such that:

```
@parent.count_all_children = 3
```

Comment: Are the children polymorphic?

Comment: In what way do you mean?

Comment: You could add a method to the `Parent` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `Parent` model `has_many` associates `AChild` and `BChild`, this is a solution for any number of child models. Drop the following method into the Parent model file:

```
def count_all_children
  counts = []
  Parent.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).each do |assoc|
    counts << self.public_send(assoc.name).count
  end
  counts.sum
end
```

That uses reflection and may be relatively slow. If you *only* have those two child models and don't intend to add (m)any more, then just sum the two:

```
def count_all_children
  self.a_childs.count + self.b_childs.count
end
```